# Pass value of a include to a variable

Tags: php, variables, include

Is it possible to pass the result of an include to a variable?

Let's consider this simple file 'example.html':

```
<p>some HTML</p>
```

In a PHP file, how can we pass the content of this file to a variable?
I tried:

```
$my_variable = include('example.html');
```

It includes the file, but the value of `$my_variable` is `1`.

Comment: Use the `ob_XXX` functions to capture the output buffer.

Comment: You have to use the buffer. Look http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Comment: The value of `$my_variable` is 1 because `include` returns `true` if it succeeds, `false` if there's an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get the content of file you can use this :

```
$data = file_get_contents("example.html");
echo htmlentities($data);
```

or this :

```
ob_start();
readfile("example.html");
$data = ob_get_clean();
echo htmlentities($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
ob_start();
include('example.html');
$output = ob_get_clean();// this will buffer your output
```