# What HTTP headers are sent when trying to "Save Page" on a browser?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, scrape

I am using CURL to retrieve a page. I have noticed that when I just view the page with the browser, a key field in a form does not appear. When attempting to do the CURL request - the field indeed does not appear.  However, when saving the page and then doing "View Source" locally, all of a sudden the hidden form field does appear.

Form field for example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="frc" id="frc" value="123">
```

I was wondering how it would be possible to simulate a "Save Page" request sent to a server by the browser. Are there any specific headers that are sent when clicking on "Save Page"?
Is there any other explanation why a certain field would all of a sudden pop up "locally"?

Comment: You want to find out more about why that field sometimes is shown and sometimes not. This has nothing to do with how the page is fetched, be it curl, a browser or some other means. What might be a different indirectly is the application of styles which are not saved when a pages local copy in a browser is saved to a file. Or some means of client side scripting that also might get lost when saving and reopening an html page.

Comment: If that field is inserted with javascript you would need to know what to insert yourself. Far too little information given for anyone to answer this. Also could be some csrf field that would change on subsequent page loads

Answer (score 0):

It's not always using HTTP headers...
You can use this to complete save page using php:

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29589363/what-http-headers-are-sent-when-trying-to-save-page-on-a-browser");
echo htmlentities($data);
```

You can save it later for your need, like save this page as `*.html` as `*.php` or etc.

Please read my answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543504/pass-value-of-a-include-to-a-variable), you can process later for your purpose...

You can use fsockopen to do that like this :

```
$server  = 'somesite or somefile'; //"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29589363/what-http-headers-are-sent-when-trying-to-save-page-on-a-browser" or "example.html"
$port    = 80;
$size    = 1024;   // Bytes will be read (and display). 0 for read all

$socket  = fsockopen( $server, $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout=100 );
fputs( $socket, $request );
if ( $size > 0 ) {

    $tmp="";
    while (!feof($socket))
    {
        $buffer = fgets($socket,$size);
        $tmp .= $buffer;
        [another code you want]
    }               
    $fp = fopen("output.txt","w");  //or, whatever output extension you want...
    fwrite($fp,$tmp);
    fclose($fp);
}

fclose( $socket );
```

For the curl it self you can use this :

```
$source = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29589363/what-http-headers-are-sent-when-trying-to-save-page-on-a-browser";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch); 
curl_close ($ch);

$destination = "output.html";
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

Hope this help you out.